# Wait for all stages to complete

Tags: java, monitor

I have a problem with monitors. I need to code two methods to make this:

There are N process, from P(0) to P(N) and each process is divided in three stages A, B and C. To make the stage B of P(0) all A stages of all process need to be completed and to complete all C stages of all process, the stage B of P(0) need to be completed. Here is an image:

[image: diagram]

And this is the code:

```
public synchronized void finA(int idProceso) throws InterruptedException {
    if(idProceso == 0)
        this.wait();
    else
        this.notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void finB(int idProceso) throws InterruptedException {
    if(idProceso == 0)
        this.wait();
    else
        this.notify();
}
```

The method `finA()` is called after the stage A of a process is finished and the same with method `finB()`.

The problem is that some C stages are done before the stage B of P(0) is done.

Comment: Maybe `CyclicBarrier` is what you are looking for?

Comment: "To make the stage B of P(0) all A stages of all process need to be completed and to complete all C stages of all process, the stage B of P(0) need to be completed.": and how are you implementing this logic?

Comment: For `B` of `P(0)` I would use one shared `new CountDownLatch(N)` and for all `C`-s - one shared `new CountDownLatch(1)`.

Comment: @callOfCode it needs to be done with monitors.